# FTP OS.Walk goes into endless loop

Tags: python, loops, ftp, os.walk

Simply trying to list files from a remote FTP folder which contains only one file (`/public_html/Data/ ['TestFile.txt']`). 
os.walk simply returns the same filename over and over in a endless loop until I don't manually interrupt. Code is:

```
import ftptool as f
a_host = f.FTPHost.connect("SomeFTPSite", user="User", password="Pass")
for (dirname, subdirs, files) in a_host.walk("/public_html/Data"):
    print (dirname, files)
```

Output looks like this:

```
/public_html/Data/ ['TestFile.txt']
/public_html/Data/ ['TestFile.txt']
/public_html/Data/ ['TestFile.txt']
/public_html/Data/ ['TestFile.txt']
/public_html/Data/ ['TestFile.txt']
/public_html/Data/ ['TestFile.txt']
/public_html/Data/ ['TestFile.txt']
/public_html/Data/ ['TestFile.txt']
/public_html/Data/ ['TestFile.txt']
/public_html/Data/ ['TestFile.txt']
/public_html/Data/ ['TestFile.txt']
/public_html/Data/ ['TestFile.txt']
/public_html/Data/ ['TestFile.txt']
/public_html/Data/ ['TestFile.txt']
/public_html/Data/ ['TestFile.txt']
```

/// Manually interrupted at this point///

Comment: Could it be a bug in the library? It's difficult for anyone to reproduce as they would have to set up an ftp site with the same directory structure.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure, but have a look at subdirs. The FTP server may be returning '.' on the listing, and looking at [ftptool code](https://github.com/bloggse/ftptool/blob/master/ftptool.py#L105), it may recur over it again and again.